# Why is 1/0 undefined?

Tags: limits

I understand that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}$$ has no definite limit, but $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}$$ in fact does. One of the properties of $0$ is that no power modifies it, so wouldn't the two functions be equivalent at $0$?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac 1{x^2}$$ does not have a definite limit. Why do you think it does?

Comment: Isn't there a definite limit of infinity?

Comment: The problem is that $x\neq 0$,you actually have some small number $x$ that goes to $0$.

Comment: Infinity is not a number, which is why we leave it undefined.

Comment: I think you were misinformed. If you replace the limit with a sum over integer values of $x$ from $1$ to infinity, then the second sum converges to a real number but the first does not. Perhaps someone has misstated that fact.

Comment: In one sense as $x \to 0,$ $1/x^2 \to +\infty,$ but the latter isn't a real number so some would say that isn't the limit.

Comment: I think your framework allows infinity to be a limit. Then the second limit is positive infinity but for the first, there is a sign problem: the limit changes depending on whether $x$ goes 0 from the left or on the right.

Comment: "One of the properties of $0$ is that no power modifies it, so wouldn't the two functions be equivalent at $0$?" Another property of $0$ is that sign doesn't modify it either, does that mean that $\frac{1}{-x^2}$ should also be equivalent to the other two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $\frac{a}{b}$ is the **unique solution** of the equation $bx=a$. Since the equation $0\cdot x=1$ has no solution, by definition, $\frac10$ *does not exist*.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck It's an answer to the question alright. My point is that division is not defined by calculus and limits and the like. It's an algebraic operation.

Comment: It is an answer to the original question that's posed in the title. It does not concern the body of the question because what op was doing there was not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I answered the question in the way that I considered best in order to clarify OP's confusion about how and why division by $0$ is not well defined. OP clearly found my answer most useful, since he *accepted* the answer. If OP says that my answer is bad, I'll gladly change it.

Comment: @infinitelycurious No, $\frac00$ is not $1$ because $1$ is not the **unique** solution to the equation $0\cdot x = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, when taking a limit, we're not actually saying $x=0$; we're just taking numbers really close to $0$. So when you say

> One of the properties of $0$ is that no power modifies it, so wouldn't the two functions be equivalent at $0$?

The difference here is that when we use $x=\varepsilon >0$, then both $\tfrac 1x$ and $\tfrac 1{x^2}$ are positive, but when $x=-\varepsilon<0$, then $\tfrac 1x$ is negative but $\tfrac 1{x^2}$ is positive. So really, this doesn't have anything to do with $0$, it's just that negative numbers squared give a positive number.

---

To expand on the fact that you say $\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x$ does not have a limit and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac 1{x^2}$ does; this is simply because, when approached from the left, the first limit should be $-\infty$, but when approached from the right, the first limit should be $+\infty$. This is why the first limit is indefinite.

The second however gives $+\infty$ no matter how you approach $0$, but this, as explained above, has to do with the fact that $(-x)^2=x^2$. There are no hole in algebra, nor are there in calculus; I suggest you read into the definition of limits again to refresh your view on this.

Comment: I guess I just see this as a problem of completion, it seems like algebra and calculus have this huge gap in hole when it comes to this. I just think there ought to be a concrete answer somewhere, otherwise is algebra really altogether valid?

Comment: Algebra and calculus do not have "gaps" in them. I'll edit my answer to elaborate on the limits.

Comment: I'm referring to how algebra was before the development of complex numbers

Comment: This has nothing to do with complex numbers.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things here that are a bit confusing, so let's break them down. We say: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} = \infty$$

But we don't actually mean that it "equals infinity". The limit is still indefinite. The notation $\lim_{x\to a} \_\_\_ = \infty$ is actually shorthand to mean "as $x$ goes to $a$, the limit goes to an arbitrarily large positive."

The second part you have here is how zero functions:

> One of the properties of $0$ is that no power modifies it, so wouldn't the two functions be equivalent at $0$?

You are correct! No power of zero modifies its value, and those two functions are "equivalent" at zero, in that they are both undefined.

The difference here is the limit. In a limit, you can approach the value (or indefinite value) from the "left" or "right" side of the variable. Whereas the limit in $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is positive no matter which direction it's approached from, the limit in $\frac{1}{x}$ is negative on the left side and positive on the right side. So, we can say that the limit for $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is arbitrarily positive, but $\frac{1}{x}$ can be positive or negative depending on which side you approach it.

Comment: Excellent answer, gets to the heart of OP's misunderstanding about limits.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the point to study the limit of a function at a point is to know the behavior of the function around that point without requiring the function to be defined at the point! You can make $1/x$ as large as you please by making $x$ sufficiently close to $0$ but $\neq 0$. In the same way, you can make $1/x^{2}$ as large as you please by making $x$ sufficiently close to $0$ but $\neq 0$. So the two functions are not said to have limit at $0$.

To address the question why $1/0$ is undefined, note that if $1/0$ is some real number $r$ then $1 = 0 \cdot r = 0$ by one of the properties shared by the usual number systems. So if you want to preserve that "nice" property then you cannot define $1/0$; and if you want to define $1/0$ then you abandon the property.

Answer (score -2):

If you have finite number of chocolates, if you give everyone exactly zero number of chocolate, you can give your chocolate to $M$ number of people. Where M is greater than, any arbitrarily large natural number. So, the limit would have converged to $+\infty$

In your problem, when you calculate the limit, both directional limit must exist, and it turns out that if you approach from either side of the limiting quantity, your limiting value changes. And so, we call that the limit does not exist.

In your second problem, directional limits does not converges to any finite number, and so in the second case also does not exist.

Note that, $\frac{x}{x}|_{x=0} = \textbf{undefined}$, while, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{x} = 1$. You can not take $0$ number of chocolate and distribute them in $0$ quantity. Isn't it?

Comment: Well, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac xx=1$$

Comment: We are only concerned to values that are near zero (not at x=0). Thus,  your statement which says that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{x} = \mathbf{undefined}$ is a big big NO!

Comment: Sorry for the misleading info.